# How can i get the list of inbound nat rules from azure lb using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have an `azure load balancer` in which i have few `inbound nat rules`, is there a way to get those data through `terraform`. The `Data source` only seems to have `azurerm_lb_rule` , but not `inbound nat rules`, am i missing something here? How can i get the data from azure load balancer inbound nat rules

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can export the `inbound_nat_rules` attribute in the `frontend_ip_configuration` block , reference [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/lb#attributes-reference).

For example:

```
output "inbound_nat_rules" {
    value = azurerm_lb.example.frontend_ip_configuration[*].inbound_nat_rules
}
```

[image]

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply, does it give the list of rules?

Comment: Yes. It can get the list of nat rules in your LB. In my example, it just has one nat rule in my LB.

Comment: how about the names and values there.

Comment: Do you want which name？

Comment: all rules that is there